# On click element should hide from parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a given task, I used "data-row" four times and in it there is a link have "Edit".

I want that when I click on "Edit", then this should hide with "data" class and display "get-input" only form current "data-row". In my query when I click on "Edit", it hide from all "data-row".

What is the logic for that?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="data-row">
    <span class="data-label">Email:</span>
    <span class="data"><a href="mailto:info@apus.edu">info@sjsu.edu</a>  </span>
    <div class="hidden get-input phone">
        <input type="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" value="877-755-2787">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="edit-contact orange f-right"> Edit</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.data-row {margin-bottom:20px}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".edit-contact").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
  $(".data").addClass("hidden");
  $(".get-input").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

[**Check Here JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dqm4mu6b/)

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dqm4mu6b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `this` reference to hide the elements related to the clicked element,

```
$(".edit-contact").click(function(){
  $(this).prev(".get-input").removeClass("hidden")
     .prev(".data").add(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

`.prev()` will select the immediate previous sibling related to the clicked element.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dqm4mu6b/2/)

Comment: That is it, thanks for very quick response Rajaprabhu :)

Comment: @JavaScriptbeginner... Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector selects all the elements with a class data. You'll need to specify which one exactly you want to add your class to. You can achieve this with: 
  `$(this).parent().children(".data").addClass("hidden");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.target to find the current clicked edit icon. below is js change for this.

```
$(".edit-contact").click(function(event){
  $(this).addClass("hidden");
  $(event.target.parentNode).find(".data").addClass("hidden");
  $(event.target.parentNode).find(".get-input").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Change and check in JS fiddle